# Command to find the pre-image of a set that is mapped to by the function $f(x)=3^x \mod{17}$

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, inverse, modular-arithmetic

$$f(x)=3^x \mod{17}$$

How to find the pre-image of the set if this function maps from real numbers to real numbers. What command would I use, to see the pre-image if the function would map from integers to integers.

It is easy to compute with mathematica, but the command to find the pre-image I cannot find.

What I tried, and there are no methods available to solve it:

```
Solve[y == 3^x - 17 Floor[3^x/17], x]
```

Output: [image]

Comment: Not sure why you'd want the pre-image for the reals. For integers, it's a discrete logarithm using `MultiplicativeOrder` like this: `pri = Table[MultiplicativeOrder[3, 17, i], {i, 17 - 1}]` and you can verify with `Table[Mod[3^y, 17], {y, pri}]`

Comment: You might also look at `PowerMod` e.g. `PowerMod[3, x, 17]`

Comment: Ok, but how to get it back, if I only know the function and the image for example.

Comment: Partial success: `domain = -1 < u < 60;
range = 3 < y < 5;
Reduce[y == PiecewiseExpand[Mod[u, 17], domain] && domain && range /. u -> 3^x, {x}, {y}, Reals]`.  Let someone else take it from here.